# How to access Gson objects that return from Api without return null pointer exception in android?

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I use retofit for getting data from Api and this is my ApiClient class

```
public class ApiClient {
   private static final String BASE_URL = BuildConfig.BASE_URL;
   private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
   public static Retrofit getClient() {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

and i use `GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create())`  to serialize null keys

and this is my ApiInterface method

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("data")
Call<MyCustomObject> getData(@Field("data") String request);
```

so i got the data binded into `MyCustomObject` and it can be as follow

```
  public class MyCustomObject{

   @SerializedName("result")
   @Expose
   private Result result;
   @SerializedName("data")
   @Expose
   private Data Data;

   public Result getResult() {
       return result;
   }

   public void setResult(Result result) {
      this.result= result;
   }

   public Data getData() {
      return data;
   }

   public void setData(Data data) {
      this.data= data;
   }

 }
```

so Data and Result objects might have some attributes that returned null and it contin a lot of attribute and when i use them in my activity it through null pointer exception and the app crash

so is there exist any method that make me not have to check every parameter in these objects that null or not ?

**Update 1**

for more information let's say that the class data as follow

```
public class Data {

 @SerializedName("type")
 @Expose
 private String type;
 @SerializedName("properties")
 @Expose
 private String properties;

 public String getType() {
   return type;
 }

 public void setType(String type) {
   this.type = type;
 }

 public String getProperties() {
   return properties;
 }

 public void setProperties(String properties) {
   this.properties = properties;
 }
}
```

so when i use getData().getType() it may through null pointer exception based on the return of api

Answer (score 0):

you can add a bit of logic to your model class so if gson get you an empty field (null) you can manage that in your model class so you dont need to manage nullpointerexceptions in all of your project .
ex:

```
public class MyCustomObject{

   @SerializedName("result")
   @Expose
   private Result result;
   @SerializedName("data")
   @Expose
   private Data Data;

   public Result getResult() {
       return (result != null) ? result : new Result();
   }

   public void setResult(Result result) {
      this.result= result;
   }

   public Data getData() {
      return (data != null) ? data : new Data();
   }

   public void setData(Data data) {
      this.data= data;
   }

 }
```

pay attention to get methods of your model .
for objects you need to find a way to initialize its arguments to show that they are not set. for example in your Data model if you have an string argument named email you can set that string as "not set".

Answer (score 0):

You can add @Nullable annotation to the fields which might return null

Comment: i updated the question, so if i add @Nullable when i try to access it, it will not through null pointer exception ?

Comment: I believe so, try it